# UITableView weird scroll behaviour with navigation bar large title, bounce effect at the top auto cut off / jerky when scroll to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with multiple sections with the header, collapsable/expandable. And also a tableHeaderView with custom `UIView`.

Using custom section header `UIView` and also custom `UITableViewCell`.

When all sections and rows are fully expanded, there is this weird scroll behavior, when I'm scrolling to the top (scroll down), when I reach the very top, the large navigation bar title should follow my scroll down gesture and animate down its way (Bounce effect). However, in this case, the bounce effect did not happen, the moment I scrolled to the top and try to scroll more for bounce effect, the scroll automatically got cut off and the navigation bar automatically becomes a small title.

Surprisingly, when I collapsed all the rows of the first section, the scroll behavior goes back to normal.

Here's a gif to show my screen recording.

https://i.imgur.com/WwXmpmZ.gifv

I have set the following to my `UITableView`:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0 
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
```

I have also tried:

```
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

This indeed solved the weird scrolling behavior, however it causes my section headers and rows to overlap with my tableHeaderView.

The way I handle the collapse/expand. If the object property `isCollapsed` is true, I just simply return 0 row for that section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == self.scheduleCount {
        //Last section
        return self.dataSource.count
    }

    guard let schedule = self.itineraryDataSource?.schedule[section] else { return 0 }

    if schedule.isCollapsed {
        return 0
    } else {
        return schedule.items.count
    }
}
```

These are all the height delegates, the last section is having different `UITableViewCell`, hence the different height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if section == self.scheduleCount {
        //Last section
        return 40
    }

    return 64
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == self.scheduleCount {
        //Last section
        return 112
    } else {
        return 76
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you inserting the new table view rows? Upload the code for the same.

Comment: @SachinVas I have edited my post to include more code on how i manage the collapse/expand and also the height delegates. 

I do these whenever the section header is tapped to collapse/expand: `self.tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .fade)`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this.

Turns out I was returning `UIView` for my `viewForHeaderInSection` and I wasn't using `tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView`. I literally init a new xib `UIView` every time I scroll the `tableView` which causes it to automatically adjust the content inset, hence, caused the jerky scroll.

So, I created new custom xib for my section header view with type `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, and simply return it at `viewForHeaderInSection`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let dayHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ItineraryDayHeaderView") as? ItineraryDayHeaderView

    // Configure View...

    return dayHeaderView
}
```